# SSRS - Expression not working after putting Subreport

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, visibility, sqlreportingservice

I have trouble regarding expression.

I have a report that has a calendar style. (Screenshot below)
[image]

I have an expression on the Day Number on the top left of the calendar cell, and it works (Which is in the top box).
Here is the expression :

=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value), " ", Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value)

But when I added my sub-report which returns the list of employees and their schedule per date, the Expression is not working anymore. Some random number appears on the top left of the box, which is supposed to be blank. (Screenshot below)

[image]

Here is the Design View :

[image]

Any solutions or suggestions? Thank you in advance, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: and if you simply empty the cell that contains the subreport it works again?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I set the visibility to "Show or hide based on an expression, then set the expression to : `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!empName.Value), True, False)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your week number from your subreport is not correctly aligning with the main report. It looks like it is using the number 7 from the next Sunday.

Comment: Hi Sir. It is correctly aligned. The day numbers are properly aligned, (May 2017). As shown in the picture, May 1, 2017 is aligned on monday (which is correct). It's just that when there should be empty spaces on the cell, it gets the number at the bottom part of the cell "May 7, 2017". I don't know why it behaves like that.